# How to display in Qtablewidget the data from sqlite.

Tags: python, sqlite, qtablewidget

Hi, I am new to python. I am trying to display data from sqlite database in Qtablewidget but getting only row count displayed in qtablewidget. Please can anyone help me to solve this issue. Below is my code...

```
patientTable = QtGui.QTableWidget()
rowcount = queryCurs.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PATIENT''').fetchone()[0]
patientTable.setRowCount(rowcount)
queryCurs.execute('''SELECT * FROM PATIENT''')
for row, form in enumerate(queryCurs):
     for column, item in enumerate(form):
            patientTable.setItem(row, column, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item)))
```

I need both rowcount and data from database to display. How do I do that?

Comment: You should probably try using a `QSqlTableModel` (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html) - this will take care of this stuff and avoids the need for manual `SELECT` statements. Check e.g. this C++ based demo, it should be straight forward to move to python: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/QSqlTableModeldemo.htm

Comment: thank you i will work on it....thanks for the reply..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how I've done it:

```
queryCurs.execute("SELECT * FROM PATIENT")
row = 0
while True:
    form = queryCurs.fetchone()
    if form == None:
        break
    for column, item in enumerate(form):
        patientTable.setItem(row, column, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item)))
    row += 1
```

Please respond if this solves your problem.

Comment: @Aleksandar--this works. i checked it , but my code what i posted, i added 2 more lines like columncount that helped me and now both row column data working fine thanks for your suggestion